# How to add colours to a facet grid in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, aes

I have made a facet_grid in ggplot, like so:

```
    ggplot(DATASET, aes((jitter(WordCount)),Retweet, group=1))+
      geom_point(aes(alpha=1/150))+
      facet_grid(Dictionary ~ ., margins = TRUE, scales = "free")+
      labs(x = "Word Count", y = "Retweet Count", title = "A")+
      theme_bw()+ 
      theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

How do I make each graph use points of a different colour?

For reference, here is the structure of my dataframe:

```
data.frame':    939006 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Retweet   : num  1388 762 748 436 342 ...
 $ id        : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Dictionary: Factor w/ 3 levels "Emotional","Moral",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ WordCount : num  1 1 2 2 1 1 3 1 2 1 ...
```

Comment: Insert `color = Dictionary` into the `aes()`.

Comment: Do you want each faceted to be it's own color, or each word count to be it's own color?

Comment: @Darren Tsai Solved it for me (embarrassingly, I was using the UK spelling of "color" and was too ignorant to realize that was an issue).

Comment: US vs. UK spelling of color/colour shouldn't matter. ggplot accepts `colour =` or `color =`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered in the comments, assign a variable to the color aesthetic.

```
ggplot(DATASET, aes(WordCount), etweet, group = 1, color = Dictonary)) +
  geom_jitter(aes(alpha = 1/150)) +
  facet_grid(Dictionary ~ ., margins = TRUE, scales = "free") +
  labs(x = "Word Count", y = "Retweet Count", title = "A") +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```